# How to create a stacked bar chart with error bars goes with the bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart with error bars showing the range of data for each bar and also showing the average values in the middle of each bar using R.
I have calculated the percentage values for each treatment group but couldn't get the plotting to work (I used ggplot2).
Would people help me with this please?

Here is my dput(perc_long) dataframe:

```
    structure(list(double_bond = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6), treatment = c("cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", 
"cocoa", "cocoa", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", 
"corn.oil", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", 
"low.fat", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", 
"corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "low.fat", 
"low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "cocoa", 
"cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", 
"corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", 
"low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", 
"cocoa", "cocoa", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", 
"corn.oil", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", 
"low.fat", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", 
"corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "low.fat", 
"low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "cocoa", 
"cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", 
"corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", 
"low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", "cocoa", 
"cocoa", "cocoa", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", "corn.oil", 
"corn.oil", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", "low.fat", 
"low.fat"), sex = c("female", "female", "female", "male", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", 
"male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", 
"male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", 
"male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "male"), pup = c("803.6", "803.6", "803.6", "807.9", 
"807.9", "807.9", "787.11", "787.11", "787.11", "782.1", "782.1", 
"824.3", "824.3", "824.3", "826.4", "826.4", "826.4", "803.6", 
"803.6", "803.6", "807.9", "807.9", "807.9", "787.11", "787.11", 
"787.11", "782.1", "782.1", "824.3", "824.3", "824.3", "826.4", 
"826.4", "826.4", "803.6", "803.6", "803.6", "807.9", "807.9", 
"807.9", "787.11", "787.11", "787.11", "782.1", "782.1", "824.3", 
"824.3", "824.3", "826.4", "826.4", "826.4", "803.6", "803.6", 
"803.6", "807.9", "807.9", "807.9", "787.11", "787.11", "787.11", 
"782.1", "782.1", "824.3", "824.3", "824.3", "826.4", "826.4", 
"826.4", "803.6", "803.6", "803.6", "807.9", "807.9", "807.9", 
"787.11", "787.11", "787.11", "782.1", "782.1", "824.3", "824.3", 
"824.3", "826.4", "826.4", "826.4", "803.6", "803.6", "803.6", 
"807.9", "807.9", "807.9", "787.11", "787.11", "787.11", "782.1", 
"782.1", "824.3", "824.3", "824.3", "826.4", "826.4", "826.4", 
"803.6", "803.6", "803.6", "807.9", "807.9", "807.9", "787.11", 
"787.11", "787.11", "782.1", "782.1", "824.3", "824.3", "824.3", 
"826.4", "826.4", "826.4"), `technical replicate` = c("1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"
), value = c(51.8259016783017, 51.9753053839728, 51.9087546604848, 
54.1415436129972, 54.1106717603064, 52.913772241572, 55.5997705545778, 
55.6194139918591, 56.4924341811521, 52.756297131807, 54.0698741374145, 
51.8812662974904, 52.8136421551165, 51.7104795077841, 52.6016034771571, 
54.1623667459167, 51.3709778819136, 37.4783604170376, 37.9648258082005, 
37.2613098424336, 36.9837523884725, 35.5170168748115, 36.6987002808052, 
30.9280647049161, 30.5828071790916, 30.4043098473196, 33.7352864271548, 
33.1412775513264, 38.2282140194999, 37.907049072222, 38.1577656645203, 
37.315779444059, 33.9454522731655, 37.3834183814927, 2.1917957463512, 
2.31005348867695, 2.32202708497018, 2.3304032274879, 2.24655313374638, 
2.2929324348191, 2.94482217712807, 2.90140047284979, 2.9136613560334, 
3.63335809842875, 3.43741626276031, 2.42122025094444, 2.72859631396282, 
2.62886987065021, 2.16798802642512, 2.07848329932106, 2.30282011257175, 
1.37355683358084, 1.33163417184091, 1.35325618079326, 1.60194281305486, 
1.75999531896682, 1.80484811674777, 1.23613997037845, 1.26540063659075, 
1.23814336702194, 1.50507177777088, 1.42448141025326, 1.45799671750431, 
1.3898724882353, 1.49045797013907, 1.16068579575874, 1.22103262661243, 
1.30455061852353, 5.91180103655643, 5.3398993015579, 5.86716928156818, 
4.20714588171676, 5.29132582973425, 5.28337161130989, 7.69334153388965, 
7.89139361737333, 7.3840983573468, 7.0529029292381, 6.68906452278431, 
4.93875698990116, 4.2598399231374, 4.91505548264727, 5.5721667920386, 
6.90143976234258, 6.29334531763275, 0.785577046834324, 0.712222405932389, 
0.817132312493561, 0.530942633891755, 0.727343252016159, 0.695409580821619, 
0.820990665356015, 0.89670383484782, 0.813687543120035, 0.636031443975096, 
0.591705490197112, 0.591002734164579, 0.518956883130934, 0.606699203401949, 
0.61998916895142, 0.815835107660219, 0.699342778021706, 0.433007241337926, 
0.366059439818573, 0.470350637256354, 0.204269442379037, 0.347093830418572, 
0.310965733924328, 0.776870393753911, 0.842880267387678, 0.753665348006122, 
0.681052191625432, 0.646180625264004, 0.481542990495236, 0.382043164195018, 
0.490672300857171, 0.561787295609959, 0.875390184981508, 0.645544909844027
)), row.names = c(NA, -119L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I used the following code to calculate min and max to show error bars and plot the bar chart:

```
perc_long$value <- as.numeric(perc_long$value)

perc_long_minmax <- perc_long %>%
  group_by (treatment, double_bond) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(value),
            lower= min(value),
            upper= max(value))

ggplot(data=perc_long_minmax, aes(x=factor(treatment), y=mean, fill=double_bond)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position="stack",
           width = 0.4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=upper,  ymin=lower), stat = 'identity', position = 'identity', width=0.15) +
  xlab(" ") + 
  ylab("Percentage (%)") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(bs) {paste0(bs, '%')}) +
  scale_fill_viridis_b()
```

However, the graph I got is like below:

[image]

How do I make the error bars to go together with their corresponding bar?